# beautiful soup getting <s> tag or getting price

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get the price from this page

```
http://www.fastfurnishings.com/Aura-Floor-Lamp-p/lsi_ls-aurafl-gy-gn.htm
```

The price is within

```
<font class="text colors_text"><b>Retail Price:<s></b> $199.00 </font><br /><b><FONT class="pricecolor colors_productprice"></s>Price: <span itemprop='price'>$139.00</span> </font></b>
```

I want this price $139.00

I have the code below but it doesnt find the price

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(value)
soup = BS(html)
foundPrice = soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop':'price'})
if found is not None:
    print "found a price"
else:
    print" No Lunk"
```

Comment: Does it work? What error do you get?

Comment: ah found it.... foundPrice is setting but looking at found to print...too late here :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the following code:

```
foundPrice = soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop':'price'})
if found is not None:
```

You assigned result of `findAll` to `foundPrice`, but `if` statement compare `found`.

Try following:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.fastfurnishings.com/Aura-Floor-Lamp-p/lsi_ls-aurafl-gy-gn.htm'
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(u)
finally:
    u.close()

span = soup.find('span', {'itemprop':'price'})
if span is not None:
    print span.string
else:
    print 'Not found'
```